# Plugin Bxslider não mostra miniatura

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Estou usando o plugin Bxslider para fazer um carrosel com miniaturas, só que já tentei de tudo e as miniaturas não aparecem de mandeira nenhuma. As imagens vem do banco, mas mesmo trocado as imagens por um simples texto não aparece. O codigo html * php é esse:

```
    <div id="bx-pager">
    <?php
    while ($img = mysql_fetch_array($query_fotos)) {
        ?>
        <a data-slide-index="<?php echo $i; ?>" href=""><img src="album/thumb/<?php echo $img['foto'] ?>" /></a>
        <?php
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

E o js está assim:

```
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    adaptiveHeight: false,
    controls : true,
    pagerCustom: '#bx-pager',
    mode: 'fade'
});
```

Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda?

Comment: A melhor dica que posso te dar é pra procurar outro plugin, o bx slider da muito problema, ele é muito instável, usar ele significa ir dormir com a animação funcionando e acordar com ela toda errada inexplicavelmente

Comment: Isso acontece porque você não colocou os "items", que seriam os elementos de dentro do elemento com a classe `bx-pager`. Tente algo como `<div class="bx-pager"><span><?php`.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que [`pagerCustom`](http://bxslider.com/options) não é para uso com carrosséis dinâmicos:

> [...] Not for use with dynamic carousels.

E também que o *Pager* não corresponde ao número de slides, mas ao número de páginas. Uma opção é usar o *callback* `buildPager`:

```
buildPager: function ( slideIndex ) {
    var img_pager = 'http://dummyimage.com/50x50/aaa/fff&text=' + (slideIndex + 1);
    return '<img class="img-pager" src="' + img_pager + '" />';
}
```

```js
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 300,
    minSlides: 3,
    maxSlides: 3,
    moveSlides: 3,
    slideMargin: 10,
    pager: true,
    pagerType: 'full',
    buildPager: function (slideIndex) {
        var img_pager = 'http://dummyimage.com/25x25/aaa/fff&text=' + (slideIndex + 1);
        return '<img class="img-pager" src="' + img_pager + '" />';
    }
});
```

```css
.bx-pager-item {
    margin: 0 5px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager, .bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
    bottom: -40px !important; /* só aqui no stacksnippet */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/master/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/master/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<div class="bxslider">
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar1" />
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar2" />
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar3" />
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar4" />
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar5" />
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar6" />
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar7" />
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar8" />
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar9" />
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar10" />
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Já que está puxando imagens do BD via, uma opção é criar um objeto JS no loop `while` (não testado):

```
<script> var pager_images = [ 
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    while ( $img = mysql_fetch_array($query_fotos) ) {
        if( $i % 3 == 0 ) { // imprime 1x a cada 3 passagens do loop 
            echo "'" . $img['foto'] . "', "; // IMPRIME 'http://url-da-foto', 
        }
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
];
</script>
```

E no `buildPager`:

```
var img_pager = pager_images[slideIndex];
```

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou estruturar com `<ul>` e `<li>`? E eu usaria a classe `bxslider` na `<ul>`

Comment: Já tentei, também não vai

Comment: Ao invés de `<div id="bx-pager"> ` tente `<div class="bxslider">` só para ver se puxa as imagens. Já usei esse plugin e nunca tive problemas